# Configuring sound output for Asus Xonar SE 5.1 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, sound, alsa, soundcard

I am currently not getting sound from a newly installed Asus Xonar SE sound card on Ubuntu 18.04. The device is recognized, but there is no sound output.

This issue is similar to the one described in this thread:
[Recognized but no sound with Asus Xonar SE in Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166561/recognized-but-no-sound-with-asus-xonar-se-in-ubuntu-19-04)

From the return of `aplay -l` I can see that the Xonar SE is `card#1`.

`aplay -l` output:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: SoundCard [Xonar SoundCard], device 3: USB Audio [USB Audio #3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I verified that `device 1` is providing sound: 
`aplay -D plughw:1,1 something.wav`

**Therefore, I know I just need to configure the default playback for `card#1` with `device 1`.**

I added a newly made config file (/etc/asound.conf) using

```
sudo nano ~/.etc/asound.conf
```

(/etc/asound.conf) file content:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1   
defaults.pcm.device 1
```

However, I am still not getting sound. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

----Edit----
Attached images of Ubuntu settings and PulseAudio
[Ubuntu settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQJeA.png)
[PulseAudio Playback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pykBP.png)
[PulseAudio Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du2XS.png)
[PulseAudio Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deraE.png)

Comment: change it to `defaults.pcm.card 2` and `defaults.pcm.device 2`

Comment: Changing `asound.conf` does not help if you are using PulseAudio. Are you?

Comment: @nobody I tried it, but no luck. I'm not sure why I would want to change it to card 2 and device 2 though because I already know the playback should be from card#1 with device 1.

```~/Downloads$ aplay -D plughw:2,2 StarWars3.wav
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1713:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
aplay: main:788: audio open error: No such file or directory```

Comment: @CL. I had PulseAudio initially, but I thought this method would work so I uninstalled PulseAudio using: 
```apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio```

However, doing so removes all the sound cards in the Ubuntu settings and still does not resolve the issue. I reinstalled PulseAudio with
`sudo apt install pulseaudio` and the sound cards are detected again. However, I tried changing configuration and volume settings in PulseAudio but still no sound.

Appreciate the help. Just started my Ubuntu journey so maybe the solution is trivial.

Comment: @CL. Added images of Ubuntu and PulseAudio settings.

Comment: As far as I know, PulseAudio does not correctly handle playing to the second device of the card in the default configuration. Try asking on the PulseAudio mailing list.

Comment: @CL. I managed to resolve the issue. From your provided info, I figured I should try doing a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 because I did not of a good way to cleanly uninstall PulseAudio which interfered with settings the defaults by changing `asound.conf`. I appreciate the help! Thanks!

Comment: I just installed the same sound card in my system running Ubuntu 20.04 with pulse audio installed.  I followed Ray's method exactly and rebooted and it worked.  I now have audio from the Xonar 5.1 LE.  Good job Ray.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve the issue. I reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 because I did not know of a good way to cleanly uninstall PulseAudio and didn't know if PulseAudio interfered with setting the defaults.

To create the /etc/asound.conf file, I did the following:

Create the file:
`sudo nano ~/etc/asound.conf`

In the file, I entered the lines:

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.pcm.device 1
```

Write using CTRL-O and exit using CTRL-X.

Reboot. **Sound working!**

Comment: I followed your method exactly (with pulse audio previously installed in Ubuntu 20.04) and rebooted and it worked.  I now have great audio from the Xonar 5.1 SE.  Thanks.